# React Native Carousel Slide

Tags: react-native

I want to create slider in carousel in react native like the example image below, Is there any library out there or some tutorial to make like the example image ?

[image: example image]

Comment: You can use Horizontal Flat list or this library https://github.com/archriss/react-native-snap-carousel

Comment: are you looking for a example?

Comment: @Ron yes if you have

Comment: @katwal-Dipak thank man for your help

Comment: you can also use this https://github.com/chilijung/react-native-carousel-view

Answer (score 0):

I found this might be helpful.

```
https://medium.com/@rossbulat/react-native-carousels-with-horizontal-scroll-views-60b0587a670c
```